# GCC & Clang - Find First Set Bit in Word using intrinsics

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I am trying to find the first set bit in machine word. Following snippet is from the `bitset` implementation in GCC that I modified to use to mask of the first x bits that I want to skip over.

```
  // mask off bits below bound
 __thisword &= (~static_cast<_WordT>(0)) << _S_whichbit(__start_from);
 auto index = __builtin_ffs(__thisword);
```

Problem is if two fold.

- Half the documentation on google says `__builtin_ffs` takes an `unsigned int` however the other half says it takes an `int`. The version of GCC that I am using expects an `int`.
- This causes my second problem if I use `int` as `_WordT` this causes undefined behavior during the left shift. If I use `unsigned int` as type I get a sign change error because `__builtin_ffs` expects an `int`.

Using left shift with an `int` gets the correct result but with warnings. What can be a work around for this?

Comment: That's code from libstdc++... which doesn't tell us anything about _your_ problem. What did you write?

Comment: @PasserBy I took `_S_whichbit` from `std::bitset`.  Rest is what I have I want to skip n bits of the word and count the position of the first set bit. thats what those two lines do. There is no `__builtin_ffs` in `std::bitset`.

Comment: g++ -Wall doesn't complain if I give it either an int or unsigned int.  What error or warning are you seeing?